# T-SQL Queries help needed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need some help in writing T-SQL queries to remove the records from the below sample data 1 & 2.

**Sample Data-1**: For the same member_id & problem_id I need to remove record with "Error" status and any records prior to "Error" status. So in the below example I need to remove records with version_id in (1,2,3,4).

```
Member_ID   Problem_ID  Version_ID  Status
AA           10            1        Active
AA           10            2       Resolved
AA           10            3        Active
AA           10            4         Error
AA           10            5         Active
```

---

**Sample Data-2**: For the same member_id & problem_id I need to remove record with "Error" status and any records prior to "Error" status until the status says "Completed" . So in the below example I need to remove records with version_id in (3,4).

```
Member_ID   Problem_ID  Version_ID  Status
AA           10            1        Active
AA           10            2       Completed
AA           10            3        Active
AA           10            4         Error
AA           10            5         Active
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot , KS.

Comment: I can't figure out what your question is.  You've described two different scenarios.  A question should be a single question.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove"? Were you just looking for a simple DELETE query, or was this more like ignored / filtered out?

Comment: Yes I need to delete those kind of records.

Comment: I need a query for each of the scenarios. Thanks,

Comment: Try doing some research on DELETE Queries: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp - if you require additional help after you've made an attempt, plenty of people will be here to assist.

Comment: @user9760165 What have you tried so far???  Have you tried Google???  Learn some SQL!!!

Answer (score 1):

So there could be issues with this solution depending on whether a status of 'Completed' or 'Error' can occur multiple times:

```
select sd.* 
-- delete sd
from SampleData sd
join (
    select Member_ID, Problem_ID,
        MaxCompleted = max(case when [Status] = 'Completed' THEN Version_ID else 0 END),
        MinErrored = min(case when [Status] = 'Error' THEN Version_ID else null end)
    from SampleData
    group by Member_ID, Problem_ID) as rm on
    sd.Member_ID = rm.Member_ID
    and sd.Problem_ID = rm.Problem_ID
    and sd.Version_ID > rm.MaxCompleted
    and sd.Version_ID <= rm.MinErrored
```

This code will let you first select/delete the rows you're looking to remove.